# Owin WsFederationAuthentication middleware only seems to support login & cookie authentication

Tags: c#, security, owin, asp.net-web-api2, saml

Using Owin is it possible to authenticate on each call to a webapi v2 service with a ws-federation saml token? It looks and sounds like this should be possible, but after setting this scenario up and debugging, it looks like the authentication has to be done in a separate POST call to the API, and then rely on a cookie to maintain the session. Thats what the WsFederationAuthenticationMiddleware seems to imply anyway [Here](http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.WsFederation/WsFederationAuthenticationHandler.cs). In particular this if statement in AuthenticateCoreAsync, which when it fails seems to quit the authentication process:

```
   // assumption: if the ContentType is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" it should be safe to read as it is small.
            if (string.Equals(Request.Method, "POST", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
              && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.ContentType)
              // May have media/type; charset=utf-8, allow partial match.
              && Request.ContentType.StartsWith("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
              && Request.Body.CanRead)
            {
```

If there is no way for this implementation to support per-call authentication, is there a way to achieve this with owin and webapi 2? Or is this considered bad practice hence the lack of support?